# How to use is.na function with dates

Tags: r

I converted variables that were stored as "dd-Mmm-yyyy" (e.g. 18-Apr-2016") to dates in the format "mm-dd-yyyy" using the following:

```
data$variable = as.Date(data$variable, "%d-%b-%Y")
```

This worked beautifully.  As an added bonus, missing values that were previously blanks now appear to be NAs in my dataset after running this command.  However, I then tried to make these NA values 0 with is.na:

```
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to fix this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: try `.Date(0)` instead

Comment: more practically, what is `0`? it's not a Date... what do you actually want to replace the `NA` dates with?

Comment: Some detail: "date 0" in POSIX is defined as 1 Jan 1970; in Excel, it's defined as `1/0/1900` (which is itself rather weird, but "date 1" is `1/1/1900`). So really, "date 0" is relative to when you want to start. Some religions might suggest different "date 0" references: Islam might prefer *"start of the 7th century CE"* ([wiki ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Islam)); Christianity might prefer year 0; etc (this is *not* meant to be a complete or biased list).

Comment: @MichaelChirico, [`?.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/base-internal.html) lists this as an internal-function, user-visible only because of their special nature. I suggest the more declarative (and unambiguous) `as.Date(0, origin="1970-01-01")`.

Answer (score 1):

A date of "0" can be ambiguous:

- POSIX time (aka epoch time, unix time, ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) defines the "0" time/date is at *"00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970"*;
- Excel date 0 is defined as as `1/0/1900` (which seems weird); similarly time 0 is `1/0/1900  12:00:00 AM`
- other social/religious organizations might prefer other references (e.g., Islam might be *"start of the 7th century CE"*, [wiki ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Islam); Christianity might prefer year 0 CE; no bias intended, no flamewars please)

In R, once you define something of class `POSIXt` or `Date`, then converting it back to a number with `as.numeric` will follow the POSIX/epoch convention, meaning that

```r
as.numeric(as.Date("1969-01-01"))
# [1] -365
```

But it never assumes epoch on ambiguous date/time entry, so you must specific it with `origin=`. (Note that I did *not* have to provide an origin in the previous command, because `"1969-01-01"` is both not-numeric and in an unambiguous date format that `as.Date` can easily interpret; `as.Date("1969")` does not work, perhaps because it could be any date within the year 1969.)

So to be unambiguous, I suggest you use

```r
as.Date(0, origin="1970-01-01")

as.POSIXct(0, origin="1970-01-01") # assumes 00:00:00 UTC
as.POSIXct(0, origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below approaches to convert NAs to 0.

```
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

mutate_all(x, ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)
mutate_all(x, ~replace_na(., 0))
```

```
library(dplyr)

# This converts at column level.
df <- df %>%
    mutate(Col1 = if_else(is.na(Col1), 0, Col1))
```

```
x <- replace(x,is.na(x),0)
```

Hope one of the above will work.

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer, if it resolved the problem